How to troubleshoot 404 Error on "Lando Pull"?
A site I've been working on for months gave me the following error during lando pull command:

ERROR ==> GET request to users/*redacted*/memberships/organizations failed with code 404: Not Found. The server responded with the message Not found.

with -v flag I get this:
at /snapshot/cli/node_modules/@lando/pantheon/lib/client.js
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) 

I've tried brand new lando init, refreshing with new machine token, it's the same error. I've failed to find relevant documentation.

There have been some recent updates to Lando core (and, in particular, the pantheon recipe) that might be at play here. If you haven't yet updated to the latest Lando beta, you should probably update. If you are on Lando 3.21, you might need to update the pantheon plugin to 1.4.x.

Thanks @jazz.
Upgrading to the Lando Beta fixed it.

I just updated to Lando v3.23.3, how do I update the pantheon plugin? My lando pull functionality seems to have completely disappeared.
